# For IBM.WMQ .Net reference, why is my code not loading an application specific version of amqmdnet.dll?

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, .net-assembly, assemblies

I have a customized version of amqmdnet.dll which is referenced in my project locally AND which is deployed with the application.

This is in the logs of the server where our application runs and which interacts with IBM queues

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies. 
         General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
         File name: 'amqmdnet, Version=7.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dd3cb1c9aae9ec97'
            at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Put(MQMessage message)
```

However, the project file (.csproj) references a totally different version of amqmdnet.dll

```
<Reference Include="amqmdnet, Version=9.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dd3cb1c9aae9ec97, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>IBM\amqmdnet.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

We are wrestling with a number of questions here

- In the server logs why is the version number of amqmdnet dll showing up as 7.5.0.0 with the same public Key token even though we have version 9.0.3.0 deployed ? There is no IBM client installed on the server (it is a barebones Azure container).
- The exception is thrown ONLY when the Put method is called. Before that a whole lot of initialization happens without a problem eg. initialization of MQQueue objects and so on. Why is the Put method of the correct assembly (9.0.3.0) trying to call a method from a different assembly version (7.5.0.0) ?

**Update** 
This was due to a system issue and a restart seems to fix it. It still does not tell us why the problem occurred but it has nothing to do with amqmdnet or possibly, even the code.

Comment: You can use a redirect in the app.config.  I can post an answer last tonight.

Comment: Any reason you specifically want to use 9.0.3 and not something newer?

Comment: @JoshMc - Even if I go to something new, I doubt the error will go away because I am not sure where it is pulling that 7.5.0.0 version number from.

Comment: You may be surprised.  9.0.3 is not supported.  9.0.4 and 9.0.5 will be supported until 9.0 goes out of support.  9.1.0.3 is the next version that was based on 9.0.5 and is considered the stable release.   You can download the win64 redist zip by googling MQC91.  I recommend trying the `amqmdnet.dll` from 9.1.0.3 first.

Comment: If your application is compiled with MQ v7.5 and is using .NET Framework version 3.5 and you are trying to run your application with MQ v9.0.3 version then you might hit this error. You need to redirect your application to use .NET Framework version 4.5.1

Comment: @subbaraoc - The application is using .NET v 4.5.2 .... So, are you saying I need to keep the .NET version of amqmdnet.dll at 3.5 but change the applocation version of .NET to 4.5.1 ?

Comment: Which `amqmdnet.dll` version was the app compiled with?

Comment: I noticed you commented that it worked and accepted my answer but now the comment is removed and the accept is gone, did you have more questions?

Comment: @JoshMC - Apologies for that. I THOUGHT that solution fixed it. However, it turned out that a lower environment works just fine without any problems. Further investigation showed that this was (believe it or not) due to a glitch in the Azure containers. The Azure containers restart fixed the problem. I admit that is far from a solution but versioning does not seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `app.config` with contents like the following to make sure the program uses a specific version of the `amqmdnet.dll`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="amqmdnet" publicKeyToken="dd3cb1c9aae9ec97" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.3.0" newVersion="9.0.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```